# Perl: use a scalar or a reference as a regex

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use a scalar or a reference as a regex  ?
code:

```
 if($packet =~ /(def|rule.*($$wan_int|$$lan_int))/){
    $rule = $1;
   }
```

produces : Can't use an undefined value as a SCALAR reference at /root/pl/fwlog line 121, <> line 1.

instead of (works!):
code:

```
if($packet =~ /(def|rule.*(pppoe|re|em|lagg|trunk)\d)/){

$rule = $1;
}
```

where $$lan_int refers to "trunk0 and $$wan_int refers to "pppoe0"
thanks

Comment: It should work if you're using scalar references.

Comment: Re <<where $$lan_int refers to "trunk0 and $$wan_int refers to "pppoe0">>, No, they don't. At least one of them is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds more like either $wan_int or $lan_int are not defined.

For instance:

```
use strict;

my $regexp = "hello";
my $ref_regexp = \$regexp;
my $string_to_test = "why hello there";
if ($string_to_test=~ /($$ref_regexp)/) {
        print "Yes $1\n";
}
```

Works fine for me and prints

```
Yes hello
```